# command-line options and arguments using getopt

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, getopt

I'm trying to write a piece of code in python to get command-line options and arguments using getopt module. 
Here is my code:

```
import getopt
import sys

def usage ():
    print('Usage')

def main():
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'xy:')
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print(err)
        usage()
        sys.exit()

    for o,a in opts:
        if o in ("-x", "--xxx"):
            print(a)
        elif o in ("-y", "--yyy"):
            print(a)
        else:
            usage()
            sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is that I can't read the argument of option `x`, but I can read the argument of `y`. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: You should take a look at http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse as the syntax is more friendly.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse is the way to go

Comment: its worth noting that the usual getopt double colon :: which is used to allow an 'optional' argument, is not supported and may 'appear' to work to newcomers due to the fact that partial matches are allowed in by default '--help::' would allow '--help' but would never get processed unless you were looking for '--help:'. They fail to mention this is not supported in the docs which kinda makes me mad because perl in this case gets a better getopt  'stock' module than python does ... of course we have optparse and argparse (ALL THAT EXTRA LEARNING FOR JUST A MISSING COLON/FEATURE BURNS MY BUTT!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'x:y:')`

http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html

> Parses command line options and
>   parameter list. args is the argument
>   list to be parsed, without the leading
>   reference to the running program.
>   Typically, this means sys.argv[1:].
>   options is the string of option
>   letters that the script wants to
>   recognize, with options that require
>   an argument followed by a colon (':';
>   i.e., the same format that Unix
>   getopt() uses).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read argument then the option should've ':' next to it, there are few options which doesn't need argument like 'help' and 'verbose' which don't need ':' to be followed.

```
import getopt
import sys

def usage ():
    print('Usage')

def main():
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'x:y:h', ['xxx=', 'yyy=', 'help='])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print(err)
        usage()
        sys.exit()

    for opt,arg in opts:
        if opt in('-h', '--help'):
            usage()
            sys.exit( 2 )
        elif opt in ('-x', '--xxx'):
            print(arg)
        elif opt in ('-y', '--yyy'):
            print(arg)
        else:
            usage()
            sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```